# Google script - Gmail.App, email body with if statement

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail-api

I am trying to create a tour confirmation email from a Google spreadsheet, based on some conditions.

I have created a variable to add if the statement and id don't show in the email.

```
var mailContent = 
'Hello '+customerName +', thank you for the booking.<br><br>'+ "You have booked: "+tourName +" - "+tourType 
+ "<br><br><b>Tour Details:</b> " 
+"<br>Travel Date: "+tourDate
 if (tourLang !== "--------"){
       +"<br>Language: "+tourLang 
  }
+"<br>Pickup adress: "+tourPickup
 if (tourTime !== ""){
    +"<br>Pickup Time: "+tourTime
 }
+"<br>Number of Participants: "+tourPax

    +"<br><br> <b>Contact Details:  </b>"
    +"<br> Main customer: "+customerName
    +"<br> Phone: "+customerPhone
    if (customerOtherNames !== ""){
    +"<br> Names of all Participants: "+customerOtherNames
    }  
GmailApp.sendEmail(
customerEmail,
'Booking Confirmation '+voucherRealNumber,
mailContent,
{
  htmlBody: mailContent,     
  attachments: [createPDF],
  bcc: "test@test.com"
});
```

And the email looks like this:

*"Hello XYZ, thank you for the booking.
You have booked: Some - Tour
Tour Details:
Travel Date: Fri Dec 24 2021"*

It stops on the first if statement. In this particular example the if statements == true, so it supposed to add the content of it so as continue the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the variable you are using when appending inside the `if` statements. You haven't specified what variable the string is to be appended that's why it didn't show the expected output. See sample script below:

#### Script:

```
  customerName = 'XYZ';
  tourName = 'Some';
  tourType = 'Tour';
  tourDate = 'Fri Dec 24 2021';
  tourLang = 'lang';
  tourTime = 'time';
  customerOtherNames = 'other names';
  tourPickup = 'pickup';
  tourPax = 'pax';
  customerPhone = 'phone';

  var mailContent =
    'Hello ' + customerName + ', thank you for the booking.<br><br>' + "You have booked: " + tourName + " - " + tourType
    + "<br><br><b>Tour Details:</b> "
    + "<br>Travel Date: " + tourDate

  if (tourLang !== "--------") {
    mailContent += "<br>Language: " + tourLang
  }
  
  mailContent += "<br>Pickup adress: " + tourPickup

  if (tourTime !== "") {
    mailContent += "<br>Pickup Time: " + tourTime
  }

  mailContent += "<br>Number of Participants: " + tourPax
    + "<br><br> <b>Contact Details:  </b>"
    + "<br> Main customer: " + customerName
    + "<br> Phone: " + customerPhone

  if (customerOtherNames !== "") {
    mailContent += "<br> Names of all Participants: " + customerOtherNames
  }

  Logger.log(mailContent);
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved the problem. It was so simple... :)

Comment: No problem @KrzysztofB. If this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: still learning stackoverflow. Thanks for your instructions, I have already accepted your question.